# GroupBy Transformation on hierarchically indexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to take my Pandas dataframe with hierarchically indexed columns and normalize the values such that the values with the same outer index sum to one. For example:

```
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('B', 1), ('B', 2)])
X = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape(5,4), columns=cols)
```

gives a dataframe X:

```
    A       B
    1   2   1   2
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
2   8   9   10  11
3   12  13  14  15
4   16  17  18  19
```

I would like to normalize the rows so that the A columns sum to 1 and the B columns sum to 1. I.e. to generate:

```
    A                       B
    1           2           1           2
0   0.000000    1.000000    0.400000    0.600000
1   0.444444    0.555556    0.461538    0.538462
2   0.470588    0.529412    0.476190    0.523810
3   0.480000    0.520000    0.482759    0.517241
4   0.484848    0.515152    0.486486    0.513514
```

The following for loop works:

```
res = []
for (k,g) in X.groupby(axis=1, level=0):
    g = g.div(g.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
    res.append(g)
res = pd.concat(res, axis=1)
```

But the one liner fails:

```
X.groupby(axis=1, level=0).transform(lambda x: x.div(x.sum(axis=1), axis=0))
```

With the error message:

ValueError: transform must return a scalar value for each group

Any idea what the issue might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is that what you want?

```
In [33]: X.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.div(x.sum(axis=1), axis=0))
Out[33]:
          A                   B
          1         2         1         2
0  0.000000  1.000000  0.400000  0.600000
1  0.444444  0.555556  0.461538  0.538462
2  0.470588  0.529412  0.476190  0.523810
3  0.480000  0.520000  0.482759  0.517241
4  0.484848  0.515152  0.486486  0.513514
```

Comment: Yep, that does it. Thanks! I don't quite get why transform doesn't work but apply seems to be more generic anyway.